# my vscode java version is different from my system java version

Tags: java, windows, console

hi im having trouble in my vscode when i run my java file when im running the file it awlays shows

```
Error: Could not find or load main class main
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: main
PS C:\Users\xdvr\Desktop\programming_language\java>
```

the main.java:

```
public class main{
    public static void main(String[]args) {
        System.out.println("test");
    }
}
```

(im bad at english)

I tried to run it in my cmd manually and it works

[image]

but when i run it on vscode this happens
[image]

and i tried to run it on  my system powershell it also works

[image: [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E97Kh.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E97Kh.png)]

i tried to check the version of the java in the 3 terminal

and vscode is the only one showing a different version of java

system cmd:
[image]

system powershell:
[image]

vscode powershell:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please try to uninstall your current java version and try to install different version, then you need to give the jvm path in your environment variable. if you want to get a clear idea please watch this [video](https://youtu.be/-O4QVijnA7Y?si=p9wYBMALL_LXaOKF)